# Not able to add Column Name in Jqgrid footer to calculate sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have below code in Jqgrid which displays the `Sum` correctly in footer of grid

```
 var colSum = $("#dataGrid").jqGrid('getCol', 'Amount', false, 'sum');
 $("#dataGrid").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Id: "Total:", Amount: colSum });
```

Now, when i try to pass the ColumnName dynamically as below

```
 var colName = arrColAndMet[0];
 var colSum = $("#dataGrid").jqGrid('getCol', colName, false, metrics);
 $("#dataGrid").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Id: "Total:", colName: colSum });
```

I am not able to display `Sum` for `Amount` Column, However, `colSum` is getting calculated correctly.

What's wrong in passing `ColName` as variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of `footerData` method is object, which property names should be `"Id"` and the value of `colName` variable. Instead of that the object literal

```
{ Id: "Total:", colName: colSum }
```

means object with properties `"Id"` and `"colName"`.

On the other side one can easy solve the problem by modifying your original code to the following:

```
var colName = arrColAndMet[0];
var colSum = $("#dataGrid").jqGrid('getCol', colName, false, metrics);
var footerData = { Id: "Total:" };
footerData[colName] = colSum;
$("#dataGrid").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', footerData);
```

where one uses `footerData[colName]` to set property, which name will be get from variable `colName`.